# New tag: antenna-modeling

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We need a new tag, **antenna-modeling**. [See this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15601/convert-nec-antenna-file-to-out-file-for-wattw%C3%A4chter) which is an example of why a new tag is needed.

I propose [tag synonyms](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) of NEC, modeling, EZNEC, mmana, and the names of other commonly used modeling software.

Suggestions?

---

Tag is created (see answers and comments below).

Answer (score 1):

I had been thinking [antenna-theory](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna-theory) already includes this, but it's certainly a common enough topic to warrant a tag of some sort and separating the general theory from the details of modeling tools.

I am not sure about whether it would be good to combine "NEC" (and variants) with antenna modeling in general. Certainly it's the most popular family of software, but it seems fitting to tag questions about specific software with the name of the software.

How about this plan:

1. Apply the tag [nec](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nec) to questions about the NEC family. (This will bump a bunch of questions since it requires individual edits.)
2. Review how many modeling questions exist that *don't* have [nec](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nec).
3. Based on the character of those questions, decide whether to generalize (and rename) the tag to [antenna-modeling](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna-modeling), introduce another tag, or leave it in that state.
4. Add synonyms as appropriate (now, not earlier, since synonyms only matter for new questions).

Comment: There's already a NEC tag? Typing NEC in the tags box produced no results, so I created this meta post.

Comment: I just verified that no nec tag exists.

Comment: @MikeWaters I mean to _create the tag_ by applying it to questions.

Comment: Searching for Mmana and mininec return <5 results each. NEC and EZNEC return about 50 each. But searches for antenna model[ing] return about 300. So, antenna-modeling should be the main tag, those two should be synonyms, but mmana and mininec should not be.

Comment: I'll ping Scott in IW. "@scot"... does not pop up his full ham.SE name.

Comment: @MikeWaters I advise restricting your searches to questions (`is:question`) — a single question may have multiple answers mentioning the topic, and questions which have merely been answered by proposing using NEC or whatever shouldn't be tagged NEC. I see 3 questions mentioning "EZNEC" and 11 mentioning "NEC" (or "4NEC2" which also matches).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think creating `antenna-modeling` as a tag (with `antenna-modelling` as a synonym for those outside the US) is a great idea. I don't even know why it needs discussion, as there are plenty of questions on the subject.

I am also in complete agreement with the suggested `nec` and `eznec` tags being synonyms for `antenna-modeling`.

Comment: I didn't realize that modelling was a word. Is it also common outside the UK?

Comment: Anyway, *antenna-mod*... will auto complete, so why do we need antenna-model**l**ing as a synonym? I only ask this because Kevin suggested that we keep the number of synonyms as few as possible.

Comment: @MikeWaters I don't remember saying that. Certainly different spellings should be added as synonyms (if they're not handled automatically, like simple plural vs. singular).

Comment: If we use the US-only spelling, it makes sense to use the non-US spelling as a synonym

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO I got that impression when you said we didn't need to create any synonyms if the terms were only used a few times, like Mmana and mininec.

Comment: @ScottEarle I'll certainly add your spelling. I just need to read up on how to create tags and synonyms.

Comment: It’s not _my_ spelling - it’s the spelling used in all English-speaking countries outside the US

Comment: @MikeWaters Ah, right. I would have meant that there's no need to create a synonym for _unusual typos_ that aren't likely to reoccur. But if there are multiple accepted spellings for a word, or multiple terms for a concept, or a common typo, those are all good synonyms.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Okay, creating the tag was easy enough. (Finding out how was *not*.) [**Tag description**](https://ham.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/672) and then [any additional synonyms](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/antenna-modeling/synonyms). Once those tasks are done, it's a matter of adding that tag to applicable questions. Anyone want to help?

Comment: @MikeWaters I will review existing questions when I get a chance.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Before you do that, could we come up with a tag description? When to use it and possibly when *not* to use it.

Comment: @MikeWaters I'd rather first explore what questions we have that suit it, and then write the description based on what we found.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Done. Edit suggestions welcome.

Comment: The synonyms do not work. Try typing nec or eznec into an *edit tags* box. How to fix?

Comment: @MikeWaters Go to https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms and click "Approve" on each of them. This won't be needed if you use the "Create synonym" button on that page (moderator only, naturally) instead of the regular "Suggest".

Comment: I believe that I have applied this tag to all the relevant questions. Likely, I missed some or applied the tag incorrectly. Also, I edited the [tag descriptions in both fields](https://ham.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/672) here. Your turn, gentlemen. :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters I did some searching and did not find anything untagged — I assume you got all the ones mentioning "NEC".